# remove class in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue I am having is if I click on the checkout button right after clicking the remove button it would still change the color of the box eventhough I already have the `$(".blueClass").removeClass('classOne');` on the jquery function. What I am trying to accomplish is that when I click on remove, the said box should not change its color when I click checkout unless I click the box again. The complete source code is on the link below.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".boxes" ).click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('classOne');
 });

 $(".btn-primary").click(function(){
  $(".classOne").addClass('blueClass');
  $(".classOne").append("<div class='wraps'><br><strong>Ordered</strong>");
  $(".classOne").append("<br><button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>Remove</button></div>");
  $(".blueClass").removeClass('classOne');

  $(".btn-info").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().removeClass('blueClass classOne').empty('');
  });
  
 });

});
```

```css
.leftbox{
 min-height: 100%;
}
.rightbox{
 min-height: 100%;
}
.boxes{
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 10px;
 min-height: 9em;
 float: left;
 margin: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
 width: 100%; 
}
.wrapper{
 padding-top: 1em;
}
.btn-holder{
 margin-top: 3em;
}

.redClass{
 background-color: red;
}
.greenClass{
 background-color: green;
}
.yellowClass{
 background-color: yellow;
}
.blueClass{
 background-color: blue;
}
.rightbox input{
 width:50%;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" col-md-3 text-center">
      Item 11
     <div class="boxes text-center">
      
     </div>
    
    </div>

<div class=" col-md-3 text-center">
      Item 12
     <div class="boxes text-center">
      
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Checkout</button>
```

Comment: Did you got the answer?

Answer (score 1):

When a `.btn-info` is clicked, the event `bubbles` to the `.boxes` element, then triggering the listener adding `.classOne` again :

```
$(".boxes" ).click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('classOne');
})
```

You want to stop this bubbling, by simply adding [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in the `.btn-info` click listener :

```
$(".btn-info").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent()
        .removeClass('blueClass classOne')
        .empty('');
});
```

And, by the way, adding the listener to the document outside the `.btn-primary` click callback as [@Ankit Agarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51762926/3341372) states is a better design, because you will add only one listener one time, not every time the checkout button is clicked.

### EDIT

---

A more proper solution I think, if you don't want to stop your event propagation, which could cause you trouble if for example you want to listen for some "general clicks" on the whole document, you can check the [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) in the `.boxes` callback, and remove the `event.stopPropagation` part in the `.btn-info` callback :

```
$(".boxes").click(function(e) {
  if(event.target === this)
      $(this).addClass('classOne');
});

$(".btn-info").click(function(){
    $(this).parent()
        .removeClass('blueClass classOne')
        .empty('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `btn-info` button is added dynamically you need to assign click event to that button using the reference of `document` object. Changing that click function will fix your issue:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".boxes" ).click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('classOne');
  });

  $(".btn-primary").click(function(){
    $(".classOne").addClass('blueClass');
    $(".classOne").append("<div class='wraps'><br><strong>Ordered</strong>");
    $(".classOne").append("<br><button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>Remove</button></div>");
    $(".blueClass").removeClass('classOne');
  });
  $(document).on("click",".btn-info",function(e){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('blueClass classOne').empty('');
  });
});
```

```css
.leftbox{
 min-height: 100%;
}
.rightbox{
 min-height: 100%;
}
.boxes{
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 10px;
 min-height: 9em;
 float: left;
 margin: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
 width: 100%; 
}
.wrapper{
 padding-top: 1em;
}
.btn-holder{
 margin-top: 3em;
}

.redClass{
 background-color: red;
}
.greenClass{
 background-color: green;
}
.yellowClass{
 background-color: yellow;
}
.blueClass{
 background-color: blue;
}
.rightbox input{
 width:50%;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" col-md-3 text-center">
    Item 11
  <div class="boxes text-center">
  </div>
</div>

<div class=" col-md-3 text-center">
    Item 12
  <div class="boxes text-center">

  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Checkout</button>
```

Comment: This does work, for some reason, but not the one you are stating :) The callback is called even without attaching it to the document, but it is called before the `.boxes` click callback. With your code the `.boxes` callback will be called first.